# Angular AOT: Function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to create dynamic routes array for RouterModule. 
As explained in [don't and do's](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts), I am exporting a function to use as my routes array:

```
export function DynamicRoutingCreation() {
  let myRoutes;
  // .. forEach loop to create dynamic array

}
```

and in my AppModule:

```
    const APP_ROUTES: Routes = DynamicRoutingCreation();
...

RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error ... Calling function 'DynamicRoutingCreation' , function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function.
```

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround for this - instead of passing `RouterModule` a function reference , I did the following :

inside `AppModule.ts`

```
..
RouterModule.forRoot([]) // pass an empty routes
..
```

later , inside `AppComponent`, reset the router with dynamic array:

```
router.resetConfig(/* dynamic function returning routes array */)
```

That worked without side effects

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by providing routes definition to `ROUTES` using function factory... (tested on Angular 4.1.2)

Modify your AppModule (app.module.ts):

change RouterModul.forRoot in imports array

```
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
...
```

to

```
RouterModule.forRoot([])
```

add this two providers in providers array:

```
... ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS
} from '@angular/core';
...  ROUTES,
} from '@angular/router';
...
providers: [
{provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, multi: true, useValue: routes},
{provide: ROUTES, multi: true, useFactory: getRoutes},
...
```

define factory function (at top of the app.module.ts file):

```
export function getRoutes() {
  return routes;
}
```

maybe you need also create new file eg: `app.routes.ts` and put your dynamic routes definitions there eg.:

```
export let routes: Routes = [
            {
                path: '',
...
routes.push(objwithsome new route) etc..
...
```

and import it in AppModule (app.module.ts).

```
import { routes } from './app.routes';
```